# Is there any way how in XAML define what is base class of any component?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I need to create wpf Page, but if i add it in visual studio and then in partial class changed the parent from System.Windows.Controls.Page to MyPage, it throws error cause partial classes must be derived from same class ( i understand the problem ,but how to instrument visual studio to create that page from my class?

Comment: Inheritance at the UI level is strongly discouraged in WPF. Subclassing WPF UI elements is strongly discouraged unless you have a `good` reason to. What are you trying to do? how is `MyPage` different from `System.Windows.Controls.Page`?

Comment: @HighCore: it has reference to the window where is frame that contains that page. That page has some controls and those controls need to communicate with that window (for instance instrument that frame to navigate to another page).

Answer (score 2):

Well you just have to replace Page tag with MyPage in XAML.

```
<local:MyPage xmlns="..." xmlns:local="your_namespace_for_MyPage>

</local:MyPage>
```

Hope this helps.